# Python SQL script not running

Tags: sql, python-2.7, pandasql

Can somebody tell me if there is a problem with the SQL statement or any other problem in this Python code? I can't get the script to run.

```
import pandas
import pandasql


def avg_weekend_temperature(filename):

    weather_data = 
    pandas.read_csv('c:/python27/data/weather_underground.csv')

    q = 'SELECT AVG(meantempi) FROM weather_data WHERE
               DATENAME(weekday,date)=Saturday OR 
               DATENAME(weekday,date)=Sunday';

    mean_weekend_temp = pandasql.sqldf(q.lower(), locals())
    print mean_weekend_temp
    return mean_weekend_temp

avg_weekend_temperature('c:/python27/data/weather_underground.csv')
```

Comment: What is the error? Weekdays should be string literals so need quotes: `'Saturday'` and `'Sunday'`. Otherwise, pandas assumes they are columns in df.

Comment: I realized I should be using the STRFDATE SQL function since my date is in the mm-dd-yyyy format. Thanks for your help!